# bootstrap tabs: subscribe to an event

Tags: javascript, events, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

my knowledge of js is very limited. I've already read the official docs and several threads on the web. Still I have some issues. I need to programmatically shows the tabs, because I have to do some operations when a tab is shown.

According to the twitter bootstrap documentation, here a small piece of code:

```
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#state">State</a></li>
        <li><a href="#graph">Graph</a></li>
        <li><a href="#setup">Setup</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="state" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>
        <div id="graph" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>  
        <div id="setup" class="tab-pane fade">
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Activating a tab");
  $(this).tab('show');
})

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    console.log("Tab activated");
    e.target // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
</script>
```

The first script activate each tab - and it's working.
The second one should subscribe to the 'shown' event and e.target should contain the activated tab's reference.

I get the first console message ("Activating a tab") but not the second. So I bet there is something I'm missing to correctly subscribing to the event.

Two problems I cannot understand. In order to get the stuff working I can't use js to activate tabs but just rely on bootstrap data-toggle item. The other strange thing is only the 'show' event will fire, the 'shown' won't. Do you know why?

Comment: you can edit your question and add updates there. I have done this for you, but in the future it is better to update your question rather then add a comment, unless replying to another user

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `data-toggle="tab"` to your links. So your first part should be rewritten like the following

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#state">State</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#graph">Graph</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#setup">Setup</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you should be able to see your `Tab activated` message in the console.